# Getting Error on woocommerce Rest API with 403 forbidden

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am getting an issue on woocommerce reset api, some time before its works fine. for the last two days i have been getting error.

wp-json/wc/v3/coupons

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

I have done changes .htaccess file.  but still getting same error.

add this one:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Complete htaccess:

Note: User has allow read and write permission .

Getting issue on woocommerce rest api 403 forbidden  according to customer consumer_key and consumer_secret.